# Web database replacement for Access

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for an online, multi-user solution to replacement MS Access.  The current configuration that I am working with performs the following tasks, which I would like to still be able to do in an online system:

- **Mail merge**: select names and email addresses from a table and send out emails based off of a template
- **Relationships between tables:**  Table B should be able to have a column which is a reference to a row in Table A
- **Custom forms**: there should be a way to create forms for simple data input, instead of  manually adding rows to the table

Hopefully there is a system like this that I could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with [Zoho Creator](http://www.zoho.com/creator/), which does everything I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out [iFreeTools Creator](http://creator.ifreetools.com), which I am building over Google App Engine.

iFreeTools Creator has all the required features and can also be hosted in your own Google App Engine account, which has free daily quotas.

The app had built-in integration with other Google services (Google Contacts, Google Docs, Google Maps and Google Apps), available even in the free version.